# Displaying xml file content in url-Java

Tags: java, xml, dropwizard

I am working on dropwizard-Java project. 
I need to display xml file in the following url,

http://localhost:9090/sitemap.xml

I have read the xml file,but don't know how to display.

If anyone knows,please help me to solve.

Answer (score 0):

An example on how to use DW + rest to return an xml content could be this:

```
@Path("/hello/world")
public class HelloWorldResource {

    @GET
    @Path("/xml")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public String xmlGet() {
        // read xml file
        // return xml content
        return "asd";
    }

}
```

The method declares it is returning xml. You now just need to read your file and return the text.

I hope this is what you wanted.

Artur